# Invoke Virtual Method on null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement fragments for a project in Android Studio. The point of the project is to select a color from a spinner in one fragment then pass it to the parent activity and then pass it from the parent activity to the second fragment to change the background color of the second fragment. The problem I am having is my listener in the palette activity is set to null despite the fact I invoke it in the `onAttach` function.

This is my code for the Fragment that causes the app to crash

```
 package edu.temple.palettecolorapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link PaletteFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link PaletteFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PaletteFragment extends Fragment {

    private String colorArr[];
    private String translationArr[];
    Context parent;
    private final String mParam1 = "colors";
    private final String mParam2 = "translation";
    public OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public PaletteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment PaletteFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PaletteFragment newInstance(String colors[], String translation[]) {
        PaletteFragment fragment = new PaletteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray("colors", colors);
        args.putStringArray("translation", translation);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.colorArr = getArguments().getStringArray(mParam1);
            this.translationArr = getArguments().getStringArray(mParam2);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.parent = context;
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) parent;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
        // this.parent = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        PaletteAdapter pa = new PaletteAdapter(parent,colorArr,translationArr);
        spinner.setAdapter(pa);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String c = colorArr[position];
                mListener.onColorSelection(c);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        return v;
    }




    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onColorSelection(String color);
    }
}
```

This is in the main activity

```
package edu.temple.palettecolorapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;

public class PaletteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PaletteFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    PaletteFragment master;
    ColorFragment subject;
    FragmentTransaction ft;
    private final String colors[] = {"blue", "green", "purple", "red", "gray", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow", "lime"};
    private boolean isSelected = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        String title = res.getString(R.string.palette_title);
        setTitle(title);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_palette);
        String translation[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.colors);
        PaletteFragment master = PaletteFragment.newInstance(colors,translation);
        ColorFragment subject = ColorFragment.newInstance("magenta");
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment1,master);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment2,subject);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onColorSelection(String color) {
        subject.updateBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble in this portion of the fragment in the 'onCreateView' method

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);
            Spinner spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            PaletteAdapter pa = new PaletteAdapter(parent,colorArr,translationArr);
            spinner.setAdapter(pa);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String c = colorArr[position];
                    mListener.onColorSelection(c);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            return v;
        }
```

The 'mListener.onColorSelection' call causes the error and this is what the output is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.temple.palettecolorapp, PID: 14867
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void edu.temple.palettecolorapp.ColorFragment.updateBackgroundColor(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at edu.temple.palettecolorapp.PaletteActivity.onColorSelection(PaletteActivity.java:45)
        at edu.temple.palettecolorapp.PaletteFragment$1.onItemSelected(PaletteFragment.java:87)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:53)
        at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Edit2: added ColorFragment 'updateBackgroundColor' method

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link ColorFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class ColorFragment extends Fragment {

    private View v;
    TextView t;
    String color;
    private final String KEY = "color";
    public ColorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters
     * @return A new instance of fragment ColorFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static ColorFragment newInstance() {
        ColorFragment fragment = new ColorFragment();

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            this.color = getArguments().getString(KEY);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_color, container, false);
        t = v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        t.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

    }

    public void updateBackgroundColor(String c){ // causing problems
        t.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(c));
    }

}
```

Comment: put logcat first .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently ColorFragment subject in PaletteActivity is null when calling #onColorSelection().

Please check the assignment of value for the variable and make sure it is not null.

```
@Override
public void onColorSelection(String color) {
    subject.updateBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

EDIT:

change the line:

```
ColorFragment subject = ColorFragment.newInstance("magenta");
```

TO:

```
subject = ColorFragment.newInstance("magenta");
```